# Enable debug symbols for CMAKE in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, cmake, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 supports built-in cmake features, I don't need to work with solution or project files anymore.

When I tried to build and debug an executable program, the output window said:

```
Module was built without symbols.
```

I couldn't set breakpoints in code. This is the debug flags set by cmake:

```
message(STATUS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
/MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
```

How can I add debug symbols in VS2017.2 (the version that uses cmake 3.7.2)?

EDIT: my settings for `x86-Debug`:

```
{
    "name": "x86-Debug",
    "generator": "Visual Studio 15 2017",
    "configurationType": "Debug",
    "buildRoot": "${env.LOCALAPPDATA}\\CMakeBuild\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
    "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
    "buildCommandArgs": "-m -v:minimal",
    "ctestCommandArgs": "",
    "variables": [
        {
            "name": "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS",
            "value": "OFF"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `/DEBUG` is a linker flag, not a compiler flag. Enabling/disabling symbols is done via one of the `/Z` compiler flags: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx. Add `/Zi` and you should be good.

Comment: CMake should have created a Debug configuration. ***cmake 3.7.2*** I would upgrade that. The current version is 3.9.0.

Comment: @drescherjm VS2017.2 supports the builtin 3.7.2, and the newer beta version 2017.3 supports 3.8.0. From my output window, it said it had created a Debug config, but I don't know why VS didn't generate symbol files.

Comment: @stijn I changed to `/Zi` and rebuilt but it still doesn't generate symbols.

Comment: That does not make a lot of sense. You probably have something else going on.